# RAM for Lenovo Thinkserver TS 440

Tags: memory, ecc

I am setting up a new Lenovo Thinkserver TS440 in my home as a workstation and as a test server. Here is the system I purchased: http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=9091972 . As you see, it has only 4GB RAM installed and I want to upgrade to 32 GB--the maximum allowed. Crucial's recommended RAM solution comes out expensive: Would cost me well over $200. Amazon has [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DCMUDCS?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=ox_sc_sfl_title_10&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DCMUDCS) which would cost me $158 at this point. But Amazon's is a Non-ECC. From my research so far, it shouldn't matter too much if I have Non-ECC?

So, given above information, will the Amazon solution work?  I will also try to find some old RAM sticks and experiment with them before forking out any money.

BTW, the Amazon RAM module is:

Crucial Ballistix Sport XT 32GB Kit (8GBx4) DDR3 1866 MT/s (PC3-14900) UDIMM 240-Pin Memory

And the recommended one from Crucial is:

8GB DDR3 PC3-12800 Unbuffered ECC 1.5V 1024Meg x 72

Please give your advice/opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, Xeons can use ECC Ram, but will work with non-ECC memory.
[It supports ECC Ram](http://ark.intel.com/products/75461/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1225-v3-8M-Cache-3_20-GHz?q=E3-1225V3), so you can use it if the motherboard supports it.
The Amazon solution will work, but [here is a list of RAM](http://pcpartpicker.com/parts/memory/#s=301600,301800,301866,302000,302133,302200,302250,302333,302400,302500,302600,302666,302800,302933,303000,303100,303200&xcx=0&sort=a7&page=1) that would work, sorted by price/GB.

It's possible that your motherboard won't support mixing both, but that 
[depends on the motherboard.](https://superuser.com/questions/21206/can-i-use-non-ecc-memory-in-a-machine-that-already-has-some-ddr2-ecc-memory)